# How to decode transaction input data on Polygon network?

Tags: transactions, web3.py

I am trying to decode the input data that was passed within a transaction. I managed to figure this out on Etherscan, however performing the complementary action on Polygonscan leaves me with an exception I do not understand. See the code below for my approach:

```py
from web3 import Web3
import requests

# api keys for etherscan and polygonscan
eth_api_key = <YOUR_ETHERSCAN_API_KEY>
pol_api_key = <YOUR_POLYGONSCAN_API_KEY>

# http providers
eth_httpprovider = <YOUR_ETH_HTTPPROVIDER_HERE>
pol_httpprovider = <YOUR_POL_HTTPPROVIDER_HERE>

# contracts of interest
eth_contract_addr = "0x1f9840a85d5aF5bf1D1762F925BDADdC4201F984" # Uniswap
pol_contract_addr = "0x308e44cA2153C61103b0DC67Fd038De650912b73" # GET Ticket NFT Factory

# transaction interacting with contract of interest
eth_tx_hash = "0x4907f0482ed87e637144b502af0ec84af4134d109c53a68f30560d4eea7be59b" # Transfer
pol_tx_hash = "0x926cf150b3882668c6514a3176f17e92c1b8c77c4d076fa83696bacab501e2fb" # Mint

# abi endpoints
eth_abi_addr = f"https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=contract&action=getabi&address={eth_contract_addr}&apikey={eth_api_key}"
pol_abi_addr = f"https://api.polygonscan.com/api?module=contract&action=getabi&address={pol_contract_addr}&apikey={pol_api_key}"

# abi data
eth_abi_data = requests.get(eth_abi_addr).json()
pol_abi_data = requests.get(pol_abi_addr).json()

# create connection to http provider
eth_w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(eth_httpprovider))
pol_w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(pol_httpprovider))
print(f'Eth node connected: {eth_w3.isConnected()}')
print(f'Pol node connected: {pol_w3.isConnected()}')

# fetch transaction data from its hash
eth_tx = eth_w3.eth.get_transaction(eth_tx_hash)
pol_tx = pol_w3.eth.get_transaction(pol_tx_hash)

# create contract objects
eth_contract = eth_w3.eth.contract(eth_tx['to'], abi=eth_abi_data['result'])
pol_contract = pol_w3.eth.contract(pol_tx['to'], abi=pol_abi_data['result'])

# decode input data
eth_func_obj, eth_func_params = eth_contract.decode_function_input(eth_tx['input'])
print(f'Function: {eth_func_obj}')
print(f'Function params: {eth_func_params}')

pol_func_obj, pol_func_params = pol_contract.decode_function_input(pol_tx['input'])
```

Which produces the following output:

```
Eth node connected: True
Pol node connected: True
Function: <Function transfer(address,uint256)>
Function params: {'dst': '0x6cC5F688a315f3dC28A7781717a9A798a59fDA7b', 'rawAmount': 11114622349243359999}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "decode_input.py", line 47, in <module>
    pol_func_obj, pol_func_params = pol_contract.decode_function_input(pol_tx['input'])
  File "/home/bram/.venv/main/lib/python3.6/site-packages/eth_utils/decorators.py", line 18, in _wrapper
    return self.method(obj, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/bram/.venv/main/lib/python3.6/site-packages/web3/contract.py", line 466, in decode_function_input
    func = self.get_function_by_selector(selector)
  File "/home/bram/.venv/main/lib/python3.6/site-packages/eth_utils/decorators.py", line 18, in _wrapper
    return self.method(obj, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/bram/.venv/main/lib/python3.6/site-packages/web3/contract.py", line 459, in get_function_by_selector
    return get_function_by_identifier(fns, 'selector')
  File "/home/bram/.venv/main/lib/python3.6/site-packages/web3/contract.py", line 1681, in get_function_by_identifier
    'Could not find any function with matching {0}'.format(identifier)
ValueError: Could not find any function with matching selector
```

What is the reason of this exception? I know that the approach to decoding should be different for contract creation, but that is not the case here.

Thanks, in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the polygon contract `0x308e44cA2153C61103b0DC67Fd038De650912b73` is a proxy, so its ABI doesn't have the full implementation.

The polygonscan page says the proxy is pointing to the contract at `0x66a9abb8e32d7c7056a886ee4b3b3eb3cc92b54b`. To decode the transaction input you should use the ABI from that contract instead.

Comment: Thank you for providing a working answer @Ismael. How did you find the contract address which the proxy is pointing to?

Comment: @BramAppel The polygonscan page has a section "read as proxy" https://polygonscan.com/address/0x308e44cA2153C61103b0DC67Fd038De650912b73#readProxyContract, that points to the proxied contract.